# Supporting multiple API versions from a single WebApp

Tags: javascript, json, api, web-applications, websocket

I've developed a client webapp in javascript which connects via websockets to various devices that provide an API.
As the project evolves we've began to add new functionality, however the roll-out of software is slow.

Essentially my question is: **Whats the best way to maintain backwards compatibility with older versions of the API?**

So far I'm tossing up between two approaches:

1. Since the device version is known, limit functionality with a whole bunch of `if, elses`. This seems messy and I imagine will be harder to maintain as the number of versions increases.
2. Asynchronously load different javascript files depending on the device version a user connectes to, essentially maintaining completely separate versions of the core app.

There may be another approach to this problem as well.
I realise this question is a bit broad but at this stage am just gathering ideas before I dive in and implement.

Comment: Is this your API that's changing, or these devices and you need to keep up with these changes but not for all?

Comment: The software on the device is changed and hence the API calls which are available. Existing calls never change, just new ones added.

Comment: To better answer your question, yes need to keep up with changes but not for all devices.